# Exporting HTML table to PDF with many columns using jsPDF

Tags: html, mysql, sql, pdf, jspdf

I'd like to link this question that doesn't have any answers. [Exporting HTML table to PDF with its format with jsPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414643/exporting-html-table-to-pdf-with-its-format-with-jspdf). I'm having the same problem with him and the tables looks exactly alike. I have a 20 column html table and I want them to be exported to pdf without any problem. I'm using jsPDF for exporting the table. I have tried the html `<colgroup>` tag for the column width of my table and it didn't work out. I have the first 8 columns showing and 12 columns hidden. I want all of them to be exported to pdf.

I'd like to try this code but I didn't know how I will execute it using my button in my html.

```
     $(document).on("click", "#btnExportToPDF", function () { 

        var table1 = 
        tableToJson($('#table1').get(0)),
        cellWidth = 35,
        rowCount = 0,
        cellContents,
        leftMargin = 2,
        topMargin = 12,
        topMarginTable = 55,
        headerRowHeight = 13,
        rowHeight = 9,

         l = {
         orientation: 'l',
         unit: 'mm',
         format: 'a3',
         compress: true,
         fontSize: 8,
         lineHeight: 1,
         autoSize: false,
         printHeaders: true
     };

    var doc = new jsPDF(l, '', '', '');

    doc.setProperties({
        title: 'Test PDF Document',
        subject: 'This is the subject',
        author: 'author',
        keywords: 'generated, javascript, web 2.0, ajax',
        creator: 'author'
    });

    doc.cellInitialize();

   $.each(table1, function (i, row)
    {

        rowCount++;

        $.each(row, function (j, cellContent) {

            if (rowCount == 1) {
                doc.margins = 1;
                doc.setFont("helvetica");
                doc.setFontType("bold");
                doc.setFontSize(9);

                doc.cell(leftMargin, topMargin, cellWidth, headerRowHeight, cellContent, i)
            }
            else if (rowCount == 2) {
                doc.margins = 1;
                doc.setFont("times ");
                doc.setFontType("italic");  // or for normal font type use ------ doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.setFontSize(8);                    

                doc.cell(leftMargin, topMargin, cellWidth, rowHeight, cellContent, i); 
            }
            else {

                doc.margins = 1;
                doc.setFont("courier ");
                doc.setFontType("bolditalic ");
                doc.setFontSize(6.5);                    

                doc.cell(leftMargin, topMargin, cellWidth, rowHeight, cellContent, i);  // 1st=left margin    2nd parameter=top margin,     3rd=row cell width      4th=Row height
            }
        })
    })

doc.save('sample Report.pdf');  })




function tableToJson(table) {
var data = [];

// first row needs to be headers
var headers = [];
for (var i=0; i<table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
    headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi,'');
}

// go through cells
for (var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++) {

    var tableRow = table.rows[i];
    var rowData = {};

    for (var j=0; j<tableRow.cells.length; j++) {

        rowData[ headers[j] ] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;

    }

    data.push(rowData);
}       

return data; }
```

This is my code btw,

```
    function demoFromHTML() {
        $(document).find('tfoot').remove();
        $('#table td:nth-child(8)').remove();
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter', true);
        // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
        // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
        source = $('#table')[0];

        // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
        // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
        // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
        // (class, of compound) at this time.
        specialElementHandlers = {
            // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 55,
            width: 522
        };
        // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
        // 'inches' in this case
        pdf.fromHTML(
        source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        margins.left, // x coord
        margins.top, { // y coord
            'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },


        function (dispose) {
            // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
            //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
            var name = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;

            pdf.save(name);
        }, margins);
        setTimeout("window.location.reload()",0.0000001);

    }
```

With this code btw, `$(document).find('tfoot').remove();  $('#table td:nth-child(8)').remove();` I remove my footer and the 8th column of my table.

Comment: where your button is add (id="btnExportToPDF") alternatively to test it open your browser console copy all the code minus the click function ($(document).on("click", "#btnExportToPDF", function () { ) paste it in the console and hit enter.

Comment: @Tasos unexpected token var ^^. I already did what you said `add (id="btnExportToPDF")` but it didn't work. :(