# export all columns of a html table to pdf using jspdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I have a small problem. I am exporting a dynamically created HTML table to PDF using `tableExport.js`: a javascript library I found online. This uses `jspdf.js`. The export is happening, no problem. The issue is that my table has around 14 columns and only 4 are exporting to pdf. How do I get the entire table into pdf and orient it to landscape as it is currently in portait? Also, is there any way to avoid the spaces being replaced by %20?

I'd also like to link this question to [Exporting HTML table to PDF with many columns using jsPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058248/exporting-html-table-to-pdf-with-many-columns-using-jspdf) as my problem is similar. I tried the code in the attached link but no effect.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I was able to change the orientation of the page but am still not getting all fields into the pdf